# Woocommerce error: Call to undefined function array_replace_recursive()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, fatal-error

I have been getting this error since I updated my woocommerce plugin:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_replace_recursive()

The errror is on line 586:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2gsW.png)

I have found some solutions in this quote here:
[Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_replace_recursive() for CI Controller solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909381/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-array-replace-recursive-for-ci-control)

But the problem is that i really do not know what to change in my code or where, in order fot the error to stop popping up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your PHP version. `array_replace_recursive` only available in PHP >= 5.3.

Reference:
[array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php)

Comment: Yup, this was the problem, PHP version is 5.2, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> since I updated my WooCommerce plugin

I suggest you check once by deactivating all plugins except WooCommerce and by activating default WordPress theme. It may be possible that any of your plugin is not compatible with the latest WooCommerce plugin.

Let me know if that doesn't work...