# WooCommerce fatal error, trying to revert to earlier version

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, fatal-error

I have already asked a question concerning this issue: [Woocommerce error: Call to undefined function array_replace_recursive()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470703/woocommerce-error-call-to-undefined-function-array-replace-recursive/43470840?noredirect=1#comment74028857_43470840)

I know what is the problem, but I have another question. What I want to know is is there any way to deprecate the WooCommerce plugin to it's previous version which did not express any issues, without restoring a full backup of my website?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: You can remove and install an old WooCommerce version, but I'm not sure the data can be restored back to 2.6.x. I would strongly consider getting a better host with a higher PHP version.

Comment: If you're still using PHP 5.2 then you're *years* behind on software updates. PHP 5.2 went End of Life in [Jan 2011](http://php.net/eol.php). PHP 7 is amazingly fast and brings with it a lot of new features and bug fixes. If your host won't update to a newer version, then it's time to find a new web host that supports PHP 7.1

Comment: Yes, you are right about everything, but the problem is the company I made the website for doesen't feel the need to upgrade their host, or change it. I tried convincing them several times, but to no avail. Just to clear things up, they have no problem with the website whatsoever, it does what it is designed to do, i'm just a perfectionist and the error is really annoying me. :)

Answer (score -1):

I just saw your issue there. you need to deactivate all your plugins, go into your cpannel and update your php to 5.3, then make sure all your plugins are updated.

Comment: Will try this as soon as possible, i'll keep you posted on the results. :)